# Prove a matrix with one negative entry has eigenvalue with positive real part

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-matrices

From numerical experiments, it appears that a (non-singular) square matrix of dimension greater than 1 with exactly one negative entry has an eigenvalue with positive real part--though not necessarily an eigenvalue in the positive reals. I am wondering how to prove or disprove this.

Clearly the result would be akin to the Perron-Frobenius theorem. But I don't know how one would build the bridge.